# fancybox open/close image view on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to open and close an image when hovering with [fancybox](http://www.fancybox.net/).

The open part I've solved, what about close on mouseout? Or is there another plugin with this default functionality?

http://www.eyerideonline.com/ - the center image - how eyeride works?

Comment: please add the part of the jQuery code where you hover on the picture using fancybox..that way we can better help you.

Comment: $("a#howitworks").fancybox().hover(function() { $(this).click(); }); - but you could see that with "View Page Source" on the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the `mouseout` function simply add another function within `hover`. Though I searched through the Fancybox plug-in and couldn't find an element to target for the mouseout function. So you may have to add an extra element that is wrapped around the image to target for `mouseout`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("a").fancybox().hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
  }, function() {
    $(*replace with element*).click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

```
$("#fancybox-outer").fancybox().mouseleave( function() {
       $("#fancybox-overlay").click();
     });
```